# Bootstrap 4 - Wide text makes column stack

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have 3 columns: col-auto (left), col (mid), col-auto (right)

col-auto are skyscraper ads (600x160) and col is a card with text. Sometimes the text inside is wide, but then my left column gets above the card and the right column gets underneath.

if the text inside isnt wide, I can shrink them and it works perfect (keeps in place and disappears because of d-none d-md-block)

yes, my overflow is set to auto and it works, but why are my columns stacking if they shouldnt be? isnt "col" set to be not stackable?

they should be next to each other no matter how wide the text inside the card is.

can anyone help out here?

Comment: please show your code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wo51cmnf/ updated, forgot the d-none d-md-block: https://jsfiddle.net/wo51cmnf/1/ if you change the text in card to a short one like "text", it works like expected

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is using "col-auto" for that wide content.  Regular "col" will not stack, but "col-auto" will attempt to fit the content, and it will use the full width of the row if necessary.

Comment: even with col it isnt working.  check my code here https://jsfiddle.net/wo51cmnf/1/ if you change the text in card to a short one like "text", it works like expected

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean.  If you remove the pre and code elements, it seems to work more as expected, but I'm assuming you probably need those elements.  The only thing I can think to do is actually assign widths to the columns (e.g. col-md-4), since that forces it to work, but it might not be ideal for your situation.

Comment: Exactly, it works without pre and code, thanks for pointing that out. But what you already said, I need those elements. fixed columns doesnt solve the problem like I need them neither